# Why isn't the following value in a || condition being set?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

The following function sets the language of a framework based on the language set in the browser:

```
util.setLang = (lang) => {
  console.log(lang)
  let selectedLang = ''
  const english = 'en' || 'en-US' || 'en-UK'
  const chinese = 'zh' || 'zh-TW' || 'zh-CN'
  if (lang === english) selectedLang = 'en'
  if (lang === chinese) selectedLang = 'zh'
  Vue.config.lang = selectedLang
}
```

When `console.log(lang)` logs 'zh'. It works. `selectedLang` is set to 'zh'. When `console.log(lang)` logs 'zh-Tw' `selectedLang` it's set to an empty string.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
const english = 'en' || 'en-US' || 'en-UK'
const chinese = 'zh' || 'zh-TW' || 'zh-CN'
```

evaluates directly to

```
const english = 'en'
const chinese = 'zh'
```

and the next lines depends on the value of `lang`

```
if (lang === english) selectedLang = 'en'
if (lang === chinese) selectedLang = 'zh'
```

while `english` and `chinese` have a single value, the comparison takes this single value amd compairs with it, but not with all three values.

Better use

```
const english = ['en', 'en-US', 'en-UK']
const chinese = ['zh', 'zh-TW', 'zh-CN']
```

with indexOf method of array and thest it with

```
if (english.indexOf(lang) !== -1) selectedLang = 'en'
if (chinese.indexOf(lang) !== -1) selectedLang = 'zh'
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't the following value in a || condition being set?

Because when you say

```
const chinese = 'zh' || 'zh-TW' || 'zh-CN'
```

It will set the `chinese` to `zh` only since `Boolean('zh')` is true.

It wont go past **zh** in this chain.

If you want to ensure that chinese language selection should be one of `'zh', 'zh-TW', 'zh-CN'` then make it

```
util.setLang = (lang) => {
  console.log(lang)
  let selectedLang = ''
  const english = ['en','en-US','en-UK'];
  const chinese = ['zh','zh-TW','zh-CN'];
  if ( english.indexOf(selectedLang) != -1 ) selectedLang = 'en'
  if ( chinese.indexOf(selectedLang) != -1 ) selectedLang = 'zh'
  Vue.config.lang = selectedLang
}
```

Even more generic solution could be

```
var constLanguages = [
  ['en','en-US','en-UK'],
  ['zh','zh-TW','zh-CN']
];
selectedLang = constLanguages.filter(function(val){
  return val.indexOf(selectedLang) != -1;
})[0];
```

This will ensure that if one of the item matches in the array, its first item will become the `selectedLang`

Answer (score 0):

Thats is because the string 
"a" || "b" 
Is always equal to "a".

You should have the or operator in the condition instead of in the string to compare with:

If(lang == 'a' || lang == 'b')